# How to Generate/Create a Unique ID to Database Rows

Tags: pentaho-data-integration

So, i am using text file input step in Pentaho Data Integration to load rows into my database. I need to create a unique ID for each row so i can identify duplicates later on in my transformation. I tried to create an ID by concatinating 3 columns into one but some rows will always be the same due to how the file is generated. I do have "true" duplicates so its been hard getting them to be identified separately. Is there any other way of identifying each row so i can make it my Primary Key and avoid duplicates?

Thank you!

Comment: Pretty sure you need a field/column in your table to be AUTO_INCREMENT, depending on what DB you're using this is done differentely. An auto increment field will always use a unique, automatically generated number, whenever a new row is inserted.

Comment: I thought about that but that will not solve the problem of duplicate entry i am referring to. Lets say i loaded the same file twice into my database. The second file will still be imported because even though its the same row it will have a different auto incremental ID if i use that method.

Comment: What about the filename ? Is it always generated randomly ? Or is it fixed for same content ?

Answer (score 0):

If your problem are not unique rows, so, identify them by using Memory Group By, use a grouping criteria and don't specify an adding function. After recognizing unique rows assign them a sequence and voila!.